# Creating personal applications using Stack Overflow/Stack Exchange API

Tags: support, app, script, api, oauth2

I want to create an application to read Stack Overflow notifications on my device.

My question: what should I provide in the `OAuth Domain` and `Application website` fields while registering the application?

Comment: Depends but it would be a  domain name you have control over and your application website (probably also on that domain)

Comment: I am running it from my browser precisely. So, would domain be localhost? And secondly, can I put my blog url as application website? @rene

Comment: Yeah, I have localhost for an app where I have a client side oauth flow. You an use any url for application website, even your profile here on SO if you have no blog.

Answer (score 4):

If you need something for personal use, it doesn't really matter. You can even use `example.com`, as long as the site doesn't redirect and change the URL. You'll need a browser and a tool like curl. Insert the client ID of the application in the URL below:

`https://stackoverflow.com/oauth?client_id=[CLIENT ID]&scope=read_inbox,no_expiry,write_access,private_info&redirect_uri=https://example.com`

This will redirect you to `https://example.com/?code=[CODE]` (note: the code ends with two closing parentheses which are part of the code).

Then, use that code (and the client ID and secret)

`curl -d "client_id=[CLIENT ID]&client_secret=[CLIENT SECRET]&code=[CODE]&redirect_uri=https://example.com" -X POST https://stackoverflow.com/oauth/access_token`

which will give you a response with your access token as follows:

```
access_token=[ACCESS TOKEN]
```