# How can I write (edit) one of my answers?

Tags: support, api, editing

I started to love the Python black formatter and I want all my code on Stack Overflow to be formatted like that. So I wanted to go over the answers and apply black / blacken-docs, check if anything went wrong and apply the change if it looks fine. I would execute that on my machine.

I'm currently struggling with the last step: Editing my answer / uploading the edited answer. How can I do that?

(In case you're interested: The current [work in progress](https://github.com/MartinThoma/algorithms/blob/master/Python/stackexchange/main.py#L40))

Answer (score 1):

You'll need an [API token](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication) with [write access](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/write), which is only available for [registered Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/apps/oauth/register). You might be able to use this very question to obtain a key for your application, or post another [placeholder](/questions/tagged/placeholder) question.

The [`/answers/{id}/edit`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/edit-answer) method is the one you're looking for. It's a POST call; the `id` parameter needs to be in the URL, the other ones as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` content in the request body. `body` is the new Markdown of the post; `comment` is the edit summary.

Comment: Does that mean it is impossible to run it locally, as I need an application domain?

Comment: You can absolutely run it locally if you only need a token for yourself. If I'm not mistaken, you can just use `localhost` as the redirect URI.

Comment: @MartinThoma I usually do it with cURL, I've written about it in more detail [here](https://stackapps.com/a/8638/34061).